# Return the first non-zero in a column/row in tableau

Tags: zero, tableau-api

I am trying to return the appearance of first non-zeros in a row. The variable I want to return is Fiscal Year that when each customer first started to buy the product.

In my case, I would like to return the Year they first started. The first appearance of "1" in each row represents when they started for the first time, so I want to return the Year for that customer when that first number appears.

```
ID  1950    1951    1953    1955    1959    1965    1968    1972    1974    1975    1976    
1               1       1           1   1   1   1   
2                                   1               
3           1                       1       1       
4                   1                   1   1   1   
5               1                   1               
6                           1                       
7                   1                               
8                   1                           1   
9                                                   
10      1       1       1       1                   1

11          1           1       1       1           
12                      1
```

Comment: Welcome! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, format the columns so we can see where the `1` values belong. Please state what you have tried already.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code writing service. What did you try s o far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: I changed your value section to a code section preserving the layout. But it seems wrong, you'll have to edit this question to make the values make sense (put them in the right place). Otherwise the chance of getting a valuable answer is pretty low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a level-of-detail (LOD) calculation. An LOD allows you to apply a calculation, in this case `min()` to a dataset for a given set of dimensions. You will need to decide whether to used `FIXED` or `INCLUDE` for your particular situation (they behave differently in the presence of filters). I'm making an assumption that your ID column is a customer Id.

```
{ INCLUDE [ID] : Min([Fiscal Year])}
```

Much more info available in the online help documents at https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html.

Comment: In the above example, you probably want either FIXED [ID] or EXCLUDE [Fiscal Year] instead of INCLUDE ID, but as Sam said, that depends on the details

Comment: LOD calcs are often a good solution for a problem like this, but you can also use table calcs -- good to learn about both approaches

Comment: Thank you Sam. I used the solution you provided it gave me what I am looking for. Really appreciate. I will try to provide more detail in future and explain clearly. Thank you again :)

Comment: Thank you to Alex too. I tried your solution too. Both gave me the same result. I feel it will be helpful for me for my other calculations in future. Thanks